# Generic name for places like village, town and cities

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms, geography

There is the German word *Ort* or *Ortschaft* which is a hypernym for places where people live like

- villages
- towns
- cities

etc.

Is there a correspondent word in English?

I don't want to use *location* or *place* because they also represent geographical entities where no people live or even just buildings.

Comment: An example sentence would help me vote up one of 3 or so answers I currently feel match.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake Actually I was looking for a database table name which contains the names of villages and cities. Since it contains a lot of smaller "Orte" I didn't want to call it "City. I didn't expect such good and extensive, interesting answers. So just go with your guts and upvote all the good answers.

Comment: [Link to chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4330744#4330744). (Between native speakers of German, BrEn, AmEn, Dutch and other languages.) The verdict is: forgetaboutit.

Comment: As John Y mentions in a comment below, on legal forms the title for the blank line intended to designate where the person lives says "**city**". I think that this strengthens the notion to use "city" as the field name in the database.

Comment: This is why The Onion goes with the term "Area Man" :)

Comment: @dotancohen: As another comment says, "city" seems to be American for this case. In Australia, a typical form will say "suburb" for this purpose, whether you live in a city's suburb or out in the bush by yourself in the middle of a farm the size of a medium European country.

Comment: Actually, ["Ort"](http://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/ort.php) does not necessarily mean the "place" (which _is_ in fact the closest English translation) _must_ be inhabited - it can be used as such, but can simply indicate any location. "Ortschaft", however, does carry that meaning, and there is no perfect global translation for it in the English language, as the numerous answers below testify.

Comment: Thanks, aaamos. Actually, here in Israel on government and other forms in English we use the word "city". If it helps, in Hebrew we use the word "ישוב" (yeshuv) which is cognate with "to sit", i.e. a settlement.

Comment: @Paola thank you for the message! I'm following the proposal now.

Comment: In Telugu ఊరు(Uru; any organized people settlement generally town, city, village etc.,), I sometimes feel difficulty in expressing this concept in English (for example when using google search).

Answer (score 37):

[Settlement](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/settlement?s=t) is the best I can think of. A collection of dwellings and other amenities that creates a community.

Comment: Except "settlement" has the connotation of being a small community on a frontier. An oil town in Alaska might be called a "settlement". I don't think anyone would think of modern New York or Los Angeles when you say "settlement".

Comment: Yes, Jay. But I am using a word that covers everything. You know, in a literal sense.

Comment: Literally you are correct, however it carries a connotation of being a small community on a frontier as @Jay suggests.  I'm neither going to vote this up nor down as it really depends on what the OP wanted - if it is a literal meaning, then it is fine, but it is not going to convey the right colloquial meaning to most English speakers.

Comment: @Jay: but then maybe that would correspond better to the German which is also about a smaller community (i.e. Ort would most likely not be used for NY or LA).

Comment: Perhaps settlement wouldn't be used to describe New York City, but it _technically_ could, since implied meaning aside, a settlement is defined as [a state of stability or permanence](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/settlement?s=t).

Comment: @Neil Sure. Frankly, that's the problem with the whole idea of a dictionary. There are lots of words that, if you took the strict definition from a dictionary, sound like they mean what you want to say. But in practice they have fine shades of meaning that may not be appropriate in the context you want to use them in. People searching for word, and especially foreigners, often get tripped up by this. (continued ...)

Comment: (... continued) I am reminded of the teacher who assigned children to look up the definitions of unfamiliar words in a dictionary and then use them in a sentence. One student came across the word "pregnant", found the definition "carrying a child", and so wrote the sentence, "The fireman climbed a ladder into the burning building and came down pregnant."

Answer (score 36):

The exact translation of 'Ortschaft' doesn't exist in English, that is, no single word that will replace 'Ortschaft' in the same contexts, but there are many words that sometimes fit depending.

- **municipality** - a legal notion of an area of living where there is a governing body (mayor/manager, council, aldermen, or the like). A village probably doesn't have this level of management. This word is probably the closest to 'Ortschaft'.
- **incorporated** (city/town/village) - incorporation' signifies that there is some organization, but modifies the more size-specific word.

The other suggestions, **settlement**, **conurbation**, **built up area**, **community**, all are appropriate in different contexts (a small town or village, a very large metropolitan area, a group of buildings, a group of like minded people, respectively).

City, town, village, incorporated, municipality all have their technical meanings in different localities and jurisdictions. In German , I take it that 'Ort' is more for describing smaller towns (e.g. Munich is probably not considered an Ortschaft).

Comment: Note that "incorporation" refers to a specific legal status. An unincorporated town is still a town.

Comment: And they are specifically N. American. A UK resident probably wouldn't associated 'incorporated' with any sort of town.

Comment: @mgb: yes, this is for AmE, I can't speak for other varieties.

Comment: @Jay: yes, without giving a thesis, I can only allude to things like that (by mention of 'technical' or 'legal').

Comment: "incorporated" is an adjective and needs a noun to be associated with, leaving you the same dilemma of what noun to use.

Comment: +1 For municipality, which was the first thing I thought of when I read this question.

Comment: @DJClayworth You could say "incorporated area", but (a) as Mgb notes, this is very specifically American, (b) would exclude unincorporated places which does not appear to be the intent, and (c) most Americans would find it confusing. So as answers go, it has technical validity, but I don't think it's useful.

Comment: 'Municipality' is probably okay in casual (educated) conversation, but technically (e.g. for an official document) it's problematic: Cities can contain many municipalities, and municipalities can contain many towns and cities. It's a legal term the meaning of which varies from country to country, making it a bit of a can of worms. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Municipality

Comment: As a non-native speaker of English, I can only wonder: is "municipality" a proper way to refer to a village? Because "municipality" sounds like a town / city with a special status (e.g., the "capital" / "administrative center" of the region).

Answer (score 19):

The word "city" can refer to any populated area. Places with only a few thousand people are routinely called "cities". I used to live in a town with a population of about 15,000, and the signs on the roads as you approached said "city limits", it was officially called "City of ...", etc. Likewise if you're filling out a form asking for your address and it says street, city, state, zip code, even people who live in the smallest communities rarely hesitate to fill in the name of that community. I've never heard someone ask, "What should I put here? I live in a small town, not a city."

However, "city" is also used to refer specifically to places with particularly large populations, as distinguished from a small town, suburb, or rural area.

So it depends on the context. If you asked someone, "What city do you live in?", people would normally understand you to mean a community of any size. But if you said, "I want to live in a city," people would probably understand you to mean a heavily-populated place. If you asked, "Do you live in a city?", someone who lived in New York or Los Angeles would immediately answer "yes"; someone who lived on a farm would answer "no"; and someone who lived in a mid-size town would probably ask what you meant.

You could say "community", but this is sometimes understood to mean a sub-division within a city or town.

"Populated area" might work, but is awkward for general conversation. It's not normally used to refer to a specific place, like you could say "the city of Boston", but you wouldn't say "the populated area of Boston". (You might say "the populated area of Detroit", to distinguish it from the areas that are empty as the people all move out. :-) But that's another story.)

*Update*

Ah, given that you say that you just need to know what to call a certain part of an address in a database: I think the simple answer is, What country is this system to be used in? Then see what they routinely call it in that country. I suggest you go to the website of the postal service of the desired country and look for instructions on how to properly address envelope. In the US and Canada, we routinely call this part of the address the "city". In Britain and Singapore, its "town". In Australia, its "suburb". Etc.  I suspect if you said "city" or "town" in the context of an address form, people in any English-speaking country would know what you meant.

Comment: This use of *city* is specifically American, too. British cities either have a Royal Charter or are very large. "I live in a small town, not a city" is definitely something a British person would ask!

Comment: If someone asked me what city I lived in, I would reply that I didn't. I live in a mid-sized town (Tullamore, Ireland).

Comment: @AndrewLeach: So on a British address form, what is the thing called which comes after the street but before the postal code (and is not the county, which I believe is optional)?

Comment: @JohnY: Generally, *Town,* which is normally followed by *County.* County can be optional if the postcode is entered, but is normally necessary -- for example there are at least three Easingtons in the North East of England.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: it's the Post Town (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_town), which could be a town, but may also be a city (e.g. London), or a borough (e.g. Barnet).

Comment: @TRiG Maybe that's what someone from Ireland would say. I don't know the conventions there. But in the US, if you asked someone what city he lives in, and he said, "I don't live in a city, I live in a small town", we would think you were just deliberately being a jerk. (In the same category with people who, when they come to a space on a form marked "sex", write "occasionally".) "City", in this context, is routinely understood to include communities of any size. No one would think it a paradox or conundrum if you said, "I live in a city with a population of 27 people."

Comment: Yes. The US is unusual in that way, @Jay.

Answer (score 12):

*Residential area* or *built-up area* are the best I can think of, but they are made by two words.

Answer (score 12):

**Locality**

It is strage that this word was used in one of the answers in the explanation with just the meaning you seek, but it was not listed as an answer.

Comment: "Locality" is also the term used when issuing SSL certificates.

Comment: Locality passes the Wikipedia test... They (Sept 2012) use the clunky but academic-friendly term Human Settlement with Locality, Settlement and Populated Place as synonyms. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_%28settlement%29

Comment: Curiously, Googling "Locality" gave me this titbit in a mysterious side box next to the search results: *"**Urban areas in Sweden** Urban area is a common English translation of the Swedish term tätort. The official term in English, used by Statistics Sweden, is, however, locality. There are 1,940 localities in Sweden. Wikipedia"*

Comment: +1. In Russian, the term that perfectly suits the requested meaning is "населённый пункт". Google and Yandex (the latter one is Russian alternative to Google) both translate "населенный пункт" as "locality". Although DeepL (which is German) translates it as "populated area".

Answer (score 11):

*Conurbation* covers towns, cities and suburbs, and so too does *built-up area*. If you want something that embraces rural areas as well, the closest you're likely to get is *settlement*, but you'd probably have to modify it by referring, for example, to *settlements both large and small*, or *rural and urban settlements*.

Comment: I don't think *conurbation* covers towns - nor even all cities (Lichfield and Ely are officially cities, but they're hardly conurbations). I agree with Google - a [conurbation](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=conurbation&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=tuqVT8CzF4ST0QXst-yrDg&sqi=2&ved=0CCgQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=e17a2aba1f011e9b) is *an **extended** urban area, typically consisting of **several towns** merging with the suburbs of **one or more cities***

Comment: Technically, a conurbation is where multiple towns and cities have sprawled into each other, such as those around Tokyo in Japan and Birmingham in the UK. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conurbation Calling a rural town or village a conurbation would be very odd indeed,

Answer (score 6):

The official generic term I've seen most often used, in contexts where such a term is needed (such as geospatial surveys), is ["populated place"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Populated_place).  Of course, that's not a single word.

In you really want a single word, and seeing as you apparently only need it for internal use ("a database table name"), I might suggest just going with ["town"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Town).  It does connote a settlement of a particular size in various regions, but the actual size range it implies varies sufficiently between different parts of the world that almost any grouping of human dwellings could be called a "town" in *some* area.  In any case, I would assume the meaning to be sufficiently clear in context.

Comment: "Town" is the winner, now that the Asker has told us what he wants it for.

Comment: I agree, "town" is a fuzzy enough term to be used generically. For example, "Our Town" is a play about the fictional Grover's Corners, population 2,642; but "On the Town" and "Wonderful Town" are both musicals about New York City, which would have had a population around 7.5 million at the time they were written.

Answer (score 4):

I've always been partial to *burg*.

Comment: Also *ville, podunk, backwater,* and *jerkwater*. Eg, [gastropoda.com](http://gastropoda.com/category/freedom-food/) and [blogspot.com](http://lakenheatholdboys.blogspot.com/2008/06/greece-vs-spain.html) have references to Washington, DC as "that backwater on the Potomac".  (The phrase "Glad to see that they got the power back on in that backwater on the Potomac" refers to a DC [power failure](http://www.swamppolitics.com/news/politics/blog/2008/06/washington_dc_hit_by_power_out.html)).

Comment: My headline would have been 'DC without AC' or something similar.  I'll be sure to call it a _backwater_ when they make me go for work next month.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest English words to Ort would be district, or, neighborhood.

Historically I think "Parish" would be closest but with the decline of the established church and the increased centralization of government in English speaking countries the meaning of Parish as a unit of government has become eroded.

Comment: "Gemeinde" would be the translation for "parish", "Ort" is not the same thing I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

I would call them *population centres*.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use the word "civic" followed by a word such as "area", "community" or some other qualifier depending on the context

Answer (score 1):

The term I would use is "urban area." It is possible that "urban" and "Ort" have a common, perhaps Latin, origin.

Example sentence: Most people in this country live crowded in "urban areas."

Comment: A village is never an urban area.

Comment: It's true that "urban area" is "not commonly" used to describe villages. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urban_area. But in Anglo-Saxon countries like Australia, Canada, and the United States, they are used to describe collections of people in certain population densities, e.g. 1,000 or 1,500 people over so many square kilometers or miles. That includes SOME villages. In English idiom, "Never say never."

Answer (score 1):

You could use [inhabitance](http://onlinedictionary.datasegment.com/word/inhabitance):

> The act of inhabiting, or the state of being inhabited

where *inhabit* means "to have residence in a place; to dwell; to live; to abide."

Answer (score 0):

I should prefer *places*, it seems to me the most neutral. Otherwise I'm just German.

---

### edit

[place](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/place): 3.c. A locality, such as a town or city

Comment: Your suggestion sounds like the German Platz.

Comment: If you mean `Platz` like a `plaza` you are right, but as often, there maybe more translations.

Answer (score 0):

I think in German there is such a generic term: Agglomeration. I'm not quite sure whether English agglomeration is used in the same way. But it may be that the term agglomeration is only used for large settlements.